# ansible restrict role execution based on when condition

Tags: ansible

I am getting error in ansible syntax while adding the `when` condition for the role .
I am using the dynamic inventory for this playbook.
below is the example of the dynamic inventory output:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "host1": {
        "Id": "1234567890",
        "enable_patching": "ENABLED"

      },
      "host2": {
        "Id": "123654290",
        "enable_patching": "DISABLED"
        }
}
}
```

below is the ansible playbook:

```
---
# This playbook will execute the inventory for applications account

- hosts: nonprod
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  vars:
    tf_project: "nonprod"
  roles:
    - { role: patching, tags: [ 'patching' ], when:  "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['enable_patching'] }}" = 'ENABLED'    }
```

I am getting below error while running the ansible playbook

```
The offending line appears to be:


    - { role: patching, tags: [ 'patching' ], when:  "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['enable_patching'] }}" = 'ENABLED'    }
                                                                                                             ^ here
```

how I can use the hostvars into the playbook? don't want to use the when condition inside the roles.

Comment: shouldn't the `=` in your `when` be an `==`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things going on here. I think some of the issues become a bit more obvious if you modify your syntax first:

```
- hosts: nonprod
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    tf_project: "nonprod"
  roles:
    - role: patching
      tags: [ 'patching' ]
      when:  "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['enable_patching'] }}" = 'ENABLED'    }
```

The immediate problem here is that if you start a value with a quote,
then the *entire* value has to be inside that quoted string. That is,
you can't write:

```
when: "some value" followed by something else
```

You can only write:

```
when: "some value followed by something else"
```

An easy way of solving this without having to deal with annoying quote escaping is to use one of YAML's quote operators, like `>`:

```
when:  >-
  hostvars[inventory_hostname]['enable_patching'] == 'ENABLED'
```

Your second problem is that `when` conditions don't take jinja
template markers (`{{...}}`).

Lastly, you use `==` to compare equality rather than `=`.

```
- hosts: nonprod
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    tf_project: "nonprod"
  roles:
    - role: patching
      tags: [ 'patching' ]
      when:  >-
        hostvars[inventory_hostname]['enable_patching'] == 'ENABLED'
```